# Multiline truncate middle is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label inside stack view with fixed height and width, the number of line is set to 2 and line breaking mode to "truncate middle". However the label's text gets truncated at it's tail. If I have single line it is getting truncated in middle. Does attributed text  restricts the middle truncation?

Answer (score 0):

@Shreeja

step 1 -> set number of lines to 0

step 2 -> set line break word wrap

Step 3 -> Remove Fix height

Happy coding :P

Comment: If the text is 3 line long , it's showing the full text without truncation. But I need it to be limited to 2 lines by showing the start and end of the text. @Hardik Bar

Comment: Please provide your Tried code in detail so i can help you on the same

Comment: I've a horizontal stack view inside which I have one label(I am using attributed text because I have link, text and the number of times it is visited, "You have viewed the web page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772059/multiline-truncate-middle-is-not-working-in-swift (2)". I've followed your steps ..I can't limit the number of lines to 2 with middle truncation. It's always getting truncated at tail. The number of times is not visible @Hardik Bar